# How to install yum "Development Tools" without internet

Tags: rhel, rhel5

I want to install Development Tools on RHEL 5.11 and my VM does not have internet on it so unable to use yum. How can I install Development tools without internet?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the RHEL 5.11 iso (or a DVD with 5.ll on it) you could use that as your repository. Mount the iso/DVD.   Create a repo ID in /etc/yum.repos.d  that points to the cdrom. (You will create a new file that points to the cdrom. Google the exact syntax).  Once this is set up yum will look at the cdrom (as well as the other locations listed in the other repo IDs for the RPMs that you need.    You can now use yum as usual to install your rpms.

Comment: Your answer would be even better if you were more precise about the syntax.